# Selecting ONE radio out of many

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to "modify/change" the way this code works, I want it to only allow ONE radio button selection out of 30 or more choices. as it is written now, it looks for all selected before submitting. im a noob, please be kind.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function checkform() {
                //make sure all picks have a checked value
                var f = document.entryForm;
                var allChecked = true;
                var allR = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
                for (var i=0; i < allR.length; i++) {
                    if(allR[i].type == 'radio') {
                        if (!radioIsChecked(allR[i].name)) {
                            allChecked = false;
                        }
                    }      
                }
                if (!allChecked) {
                    return confirm('One or more picks are missing for the current week.  Do you wish to submit anyway?');
                }
                return true;
            }
            function radioIsChecked(elmName) {
                var elements = document.getElementsByName(elmName);
                for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                    if (elements[i].checked) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
            </script>
```

Comment: So what does your form look like now? Is it all radios? Why don't you make them into a radio group(give them all the same name value name="theseHereRadios") then they could only select 1?

Answer (score 0):

Use a counter instead of a flag for "allChecked".

Set it to zero. If the element is checked, use `allChecked++` then check to see if the value is ONE at the end.

Comment: I'm real new at this, and probably way over my head in this. can you elaborate in more details about this.

Comment: Usually radio buttons are supposed to allow you check one item our of many. You can group them, but one should be checked per group. If you have a selection that allows more than one item to be selected, we use checkboxes instead.

Comment: The way the page loads up is complex,

Comment: Its a survivor football page. 30 teams (radio buttons). loads from a weekly database, and the teams playing each other changes.  i just need the javascript to scan all radios and only allow one button picked on submit.

Comment: If the radio buttons have the same NAME then only one CAN be picked. You just need to check if one has been selected or not.